# Cannot access PPA... please check your internet connection

Tags: networking, apt, ppa

i've tried to add a repository with:

> sudo apt-add-repository ppa:gottcode/gcppaCannot access PPA

but the system echoed:

> Cannot access PPA (https://launchpad.net/api/1.0/~gottcode/+archive/gcppa) to get PPA
>   information, please check your internet connection.

even though my internet connection is working fine.

Comment: What is it that you're trying to install?

Comment: What version is your Ubuntu? Does the ppa has package for your Ubuntu version?

Comment: @Mitch, i'm trying to install a software called Kapow, as mentioned here - http://www.hecticgeek.com/2012/08/keep-track-of-the-working-hours-of-your-projects-with-kapow/

Comment: @llt, my version is 12.04. how can i tell if there is a version for me or not? from the link above i'm guessing that there is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To install Kapow, you need to download the [32bit version](http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/gottcode/xUbuntu_13.04/i386/kapow_1.4.4-1_i386.deb), or the [64bit version](http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/gottcode/xUbuntu_13.04/amd64/kapow_1.4.4-1_amd64.deb).

Once downloaded ( probably the Downloads folder), just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, navigate to the download location, and run the command(s) below:

```
sudo dpkg -i <package_name>
```

Once the installation is done, search for Kapow in Dash, and click on it.

[image]