# Cannot access PPA

Tags: apt, ppa

I know there already exits a post on this ([Cannot access PPA... please check your internet connection](https://askubuntu.com/questions/297664/cannot-access-ppa-please-check-your-internet-connection)) which doesn't answer my problem.

I was trying to download TLP on Ubuntu-13.04 and I got the following errors while adding a PPA:

```
royal@royal-Vostro-3550:~$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:linrunner/tlp  
Cannot access PPA (https://launchpad.net/api/1.0/~linrunner/+archive/tlp) to get PPA information, please check your internet connection.
```

Comment: sudo add-apt-repository ppa:linrunner/tlp -y  < http://askubuntu.com/questions/285434/is-there-a-power-saving-application-similar-to-jupiter/285681#285681 >

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add it, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:linrunner/tlp
```

Just tested it, and it works.

You may want to check your internet connection.  Open Firefox or the browser that you use, and see if your start page loads.  Also you can try `ping -c3 www.google.com`, and see if you get a response.

Comment: add-apt-repository and apt-add-repository are the same. Besides, a command not found error would show if the command is incorrect, which in the provided output, does not.

Comment: @llt  Thanks.  I didn't know that :)

Comment: but your answer did solve the question :)